# Interbase SQL statement not working

Tags: sql, delphi, delphi-7, interbase

I am trying to write a SQL Statement for Interbase.

Whats wrong with this SQL?

md_master (trm) = Master Table
cd_Med (cdt) = Detail table

```
SELECT trm.seq_no, trm.recipient_id, trm.payee_fullname, trm.payee_address1, trm.payee_address2, trm.payee_address3, trm.payee_address_city, trm.payee_address_state, trm.recip_zip, trm.recip_zip_4, trm.recip_zip_4_2, trm.check_no, trm.check_date, trm.check_amount,
cdt.com_ss_source_sys, cdt.cd_pay_date, cdt.com_set_amount,
bnk.name, bnk.address, bnk.transit_routing,
act.acct_no
FROM md_master trm, cd_med cdt, accounts act, banks bnk
join cd_med on cdt.master_id = trm.id
join accounts on act.acct_id = trm.account_tag
join banks on bnk.bank_id = act.bank_id
ORDER BY cdt.master_id
```

I don't get an error, the computer just keeps crunching away and hangs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know about Interbase specifically, but that FROM clause seems a little strange (perhaps just some syntax I'm not familiar with though). Does this help?

```
...
FROM md_master trm
join cd_med cdt on cdt.master_id = trm.id
join accounts act on act.acct_id = trm.account_tag
join banks bnk on bnk.bank_id = act.bank_id
```

By the way, you have no WHERE clause so if any of these tables is large, I wouldn't be overly surprised that it takes a long time to run.

Comment: I tried it on a master table with 50 records. I didn't get an exact count on the detail and additional tables. Ill give your example a try

Comment: That will do it!  I see what i did wrong. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have been bitten by an anti-pattern called `implicit join syntax`

```
SELECT * FROM table_with_a_1000rows, othertable_with_a_1000rows
```

Will do a cross-join on both tables selecting 1 million rows in the output.

You are doing:

```
FROM md_master trm, cd_med cdt, accounts act, banks bnk
```

A cross join on 4 tables *(combined with normal joins afterwards)*, which could easily generate many billions of rows.
No wonder interbase hangs; it is working until the end of time to generate more rows then there are atoms in the universe.

**The solution**
Never use `,` after the FROM clause, that is an implicit join and it is evil.
Only use explicit joins, like so:

```
SELECT 
  trm.seq_no, trm.recipient_id, trm.payee_fullname, trm.payee_address1
  , trm.payee_address2, trm.payee_address3, trm.payee_address_city
  , trm.payee_address_state, trm.recip_zip, trm.recip_zip_4, trm.recip_zip_4_2
  , trm.check_no, trm.check_date, trm.check_amount
  , cdt.com_ss_source_sys, cdt.cd_pay_date, cdt.com_set_amount
  , bnk.name, bnk.address, bnk.transit_routing
  , act.acct_no
FROM md_master trm
join cd_med on cdt.master_id = trm.id
join accounts on act.acct_id = trm.account_tag
join banks on bnk.bank_id = act.bank_id
ORDER BY cdt.master_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The error lie in the from clause. You are using half with comma separated tables without a relation in where clause and half with joins.

Just use joins and all should work fine

Comment: can you give me an example please

Comment: change in FROM md_master trm join cd_med cdt on cdt.master_id = trm.id join accounts  act on act.acct_id = trm.account_tag join banks bnk on bnk.bank_id = act.bank_id should work